# Contraction principle and ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, banach-spaces, schwartz-space

I would like to find a bounded $C^{\infty}$ solution of the following equation:
$$- \frac{d^2}{dx^2} u + u -\epsilon u^2 = f,$$
where $f$ is a function in the Schwartz space and $\epsilon >0$ is sufficiently small.

**My attempt**
Applying the Fourier transform on both sides, I get
$$\widehat{f}(\xi) = (1+ \xi) \widehat{u}(\xi) - \epsilon \widehat{u^2}(\xi).$$
Now, I also tried to express the last term using the convolution theorem, but then I don’t see how this can be helpful in order to define a contraction on a complete metric space (which in this case I think it should be the space
$$ C^1_b(\mathbb{R})  := \{u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \, | \,  u\in C^1 \, \, \text{and} \, \, u \, \text{bounded}\}$$
equipped with the $C^1$-norm, which is Banach.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to write down a solution or prove that a solution exists?

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan try to find a solution.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to write a closed-form analytic solution. However, as the system is perturbative, you may try an asymptotic expansion in powers of $\epsilon$.

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan Thanks for your comment! So, is it possible to show the existence of a solution without necessarily find it?

Comment: Yes, certainly. For this, you will probably want to use the contraction mapping argument that you discussed briefly.

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan ok I will try, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a sketch of the argument, and you can fill in the details. We can re-write your second order system as the coupled first order system:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
u_x&=v\\
v_x&=u-f-\epsilon u^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We next introduce the integral formulation of the above system:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
u(x)-u(0)&=\int_0^xu_xds=\int_0^xvds\\
v(x)-v(0)&=\int_0^xv_xds=\int_0^x(u-f-\epsilon u^2)ds
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Therefore, we define the operator $T:C_b^\infty\times C_b^\infty\rightarrow C_b^\infty\times C_b^\infty$ as
\begin{equation}
T(u,v)=\big{(}u(0)+\int_0^xvds,v(0)+\int_0^x(u-f-\epsilon u^2)ds \big{)}.
\end{equation}
We equip the space $C_b^\infty\times C_b^\infty$ with the natural product norm $||(u,v)||=\sqrt{||u||^2_\infty+||v||_\infty^2}$, which makes $C_b^\infty\times C_b^\infty$ a Banach space.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&||T(u_1,v_1)-T(u_2,v_2)||\\
&= ||\Big{(}u_1(0)-u_2(0)+\int_0^x(v_1-v_2)ds, v_1(0)-v_2(0)+\int_0^x(u_1-f-\epsilon u_1^2)-(u_2-f-\epsilon u_2^2)ds\Big{)}||\\
&=||\Big{(}\int_0^x(v_1-v_2)ds, \int_0^x(u_1-u_2)+\epsilon(u_2^2-u_1^2)ds\Big{)}||
\end{split}
\end{equation}
After a bit of arithmetic, one finds that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
||T(u_1,v_1)-T(u_2,v_2)||\leq x\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2M}||(u_1,v_1)-(u_2,v_2)||,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $M$ is independent of $u_1,v_1,u_2,v_2$. Therefore, choosing $x$ to be suitably small implies that T is a contraction mapping. Hence, there is at least a local solution.

You should also try to extend my argument to see if T is in fact a global contraction mapping and hence there would be a global solution.

Comment: How is $M$ independent of $(u_1+u_2)$? Is there some a-priori bound?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the hidden details. One can assume $u_1,u_2$ are within a closed ball of radius $r$ for example.

Comment: Many thanks, it is very clear now!